# Finding an instrumental variable for unemployment

Tags: econometrics

I have the following regression model:

Marijuana Usei = β0 + β1Unemployedi + β2Personal Incomei + β3Educational Attainmenti+ β4Sexi + β5Agei + β6Racei + εi

The model is a probit model

I need to find an instrumental variable (IV)for the "unemployed" variable. What criteria would this IV have to meet?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main criteria for defining an IV:

(i) It causes variation in the treatment variable;
(ii) It does not have a direct effect on the outcome variable, only indirectly through the
treatment variable.

https://umanitoba.ca/faculties/health_sciences/medicine/units/chs/departmental_units/mchp/protocol/media/Instrumental_variables.pdf

In this case I would say look at these data sets:

unemployment claims data;

employment to population ratios;

labor force participation rates;

I found this paper that could help your efforts:
Bartik, Timothy, Instrumental Variable Estimates of the Labor Market Spillover Effects of Welfare Reform (April 2002). W.E. Upjohn Institute Staff Working Paper No. 02-78. Available at SSRN: https://ssrn.com/abstract=313160 or http://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.313160